# Amplify datastore deletes children relation

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

```
type Grouprequest
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }, { allow: public, provider: apiKey }]) {
  groupId: ID!
  group: Group @hasOne(fields: ["groupId"])
}
```

I have this schema model. Whenever i delete the `Grouprequest` it also deletes the group.

```
DataStore.delete(Grouprequest, requestId)
```

Is it possible to tell amplify that it should not delete the `Group` when i delete `Grouprequest`

Comment: I've the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. You need to reverse the relationship. In current case, update the schema to:

```js
type Grouprequest
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }, { allow: public, provider: apiKey }]) {
id: ID!
  groupId: ID!
  group: Group @belongsTo(fields: ["groupId"])
}

type Group
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }, { allow: public, provider: apiKey }]) {
  id: ID!
  groupRequests: [GroupRequest] @hasMany(fields: ["id"])
}
```